# How to create a custom plugin in Javascript for hybrid mobile application?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, cordova-plugins

How to create a custom plugin in Javascript for hybrid mobile application and Use the same plugin in Hybrid Mobile Application. How to write Cordova Plugins – Ionic and the Mobile Web.
If anyone knows the same then please add your answer with proper steps.

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide/plugin-development/android/ ??

Comment: It says, A plugin will consist of at least a single Java class that extends the CordovaPlugin class. But can we do the same only purely using Javascript.?

Comment: no you cannot as thats the point of cordova to plugin it interfaces with android i.e. in Java so you will have to use Java and not javascript

Comment: ok. Got you. Thanks.

Comment: A plugin can be only javascript code and the plugin.xml file, but you can't access any native functionality this way.